# Angular $httpBackend.expectGET - respond with 409 status & custom statusText

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to create a $httpBackend.expectGET in a unit test to return a status of 409 and a custom statusText of 'TestPhrase'.

Looking at the Angular docs ([https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend)) it gives the following example of what is returned:

> {function([status,] data[, headers, statusText]) |
>   function(function(method, url, data, headers)}

Having trouble understanding how to interpret the above example.

My current code is:

```
      $httpBackend
        .expectGET('/example/url')
        .respond(function () {
          return ['409', ['TestPhrase'], {}];
        });
```

The code i'm testing is:

> ```
>   $http.get('/example/url').then(function (response) {
>       console.log('success, status ' + response.status);
>       console.log('success, statusText ' + response.statusText);
>   }, function(response) {
>       console.log('error, status ' + response.status);
>       console.log('error, statusText ' + response.statusText);
>     }
>   });
> ```

The output to console I am receiving from this test is:

```
'error, status 409'
'error, statusText '
```

Expected output is:

```
'error, status 409'
'error, statusText TestPhrase'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation says:

> **respond** – `{function([status,] data[, headers, statusText]) | function(function(method, url, data, headers)}` – The respond method takes a set of static data to be returned or a function that can return an array containing response status (number), response data (string), response headers (Object), and the text for the status (string).

You're doing the second option, passing a function that returns an array. Here's what should work. Status text is the 4th item. (For clarity, I included the optional function parameters.)

```
$httpBackend
.expectGET('/example/url')
.respond(function (method, url, data, headers) {
    return [409, 'response body', {}, 'TestPhrase'];
});
```